# Replace array of chars in a string

Tags: javascript, character-encoding

I'm looking for a function that does replaceAll with any start and endcharacter.

I know I can use the regex notation:

```
string=string.replace(/a/g,"b");
```

However, because the searched char is in a regex, I sometimes need to escape that character and sometimes not, which is annoying if I want to do this for a full list of chars

```
convertEncoding= function(string) {
   var charMap= {'"':"&quot;",'&':"&amp;",...}

   for (startChar in charMap) {
      endChar=charMap[startChar];
      string= string.replaceAll(startChar,endChar);
   }
}
```

Is they a good way to write that function replaceAll, without doing a for loop and using `String.replace()` (eg the naive way) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use escape the RegExp special characters in the strings such as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6969486/519995:

and then you can use the regexp global replace

```
function escapeRegExp(str) {
   return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}

for (startChar in charMap) {
   endChar=charMap[startChar];
   result = string.replace(RegExp(escapeRegExp(startChar), 'g'), endChar);
}
```

Comment: Ok, actually I think this would be kind of slow, I'd rather write the regexes myself.

Comment: @edi9999  
1) I doubt this would be slow - at least nothing a human would notice unless you convert millions of encodings  

2) you can escape the strings only once on startup and not each time you convertEncoding  so its only a tiny bit slower on startup  

3) doing it yourself will take more time to develop (write, test, debug, maintain, read)

Comment: Ok, I've tested it and that's true